# Converting BLOB Data Into base64 and Then Display it

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2012, base64, blob

I am trying to convert BLOB data that's coming from MySQL database to Base64 and then displaying this to an jpg image.. here's the code am using:

```
using (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection connection = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection("S;Port=P;Database=DB;Uid=U;Pwd=P"))
            {
                connection.Open();
               MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
               cmd.CommandText = "SELECT blobValue FROM Table WHERE blob_id = '333'";

               MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader datr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (datr.Read())
                {


                    byte[] xx = (byte[])datr.GetValue(0);

                    string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(xx, 0, xx.Length);
                    Image1.ImageUrl = "data:image/jpg;base64," + base64String;

                    }
```

I guess am not having a problem with the code, but when running the code i get an empty picture, like this one --> [image]

Please some help.

Comment: Did you debug your code step by step? What is the exact value of your Image1.ImageUrl when you debug it? Are you sure this image is avaiable? Are you sure your `blob_id` column is not numeric type?

Comment: @SonerGönül, blob_id is a "varchar" type and yes i debugged the code.

Comment: What is the length of your base64String? Is this one any browser or just in IE not working? If you write the `byte[] xx` to a file, does it show the image in Paint?

Comment: @rene, i don't know the length of base64String.. also i am using chrome for running the website, and i tried to convert that byte to image using online tools it also shows nothing!.

Comment: do a base64String.Length in the immediate window. Add a call `File.WriteAllBytes(@"c:\some\path\file.jpeg",xx);` after you did GetValue. Opene the file.jpeg in mspaint.

Comment: @rene, Base64 length is 16, and file.jpeg is not showing anything after saving and viewing it.

Comment: @rene tried to open in paint, it says ---> This is not a valid bitmap file, or it's format is not currently supported

Comment: You could try if Paint.net wants to eat it but it look like your blob is not valid.

Comment: @rene, yea i guess it's not valid, cause am inserting that picture from android application, and sending that value to DB as string (But the content of the string is blob), so it's really confusing.

Answer (score 3):

Use following code.

```
public string BlobToStringConverter(OracleDbType.Blob blobObject){
    if (blobObject != null){
        return  Encoding.UTF8.GetString((byte[])(blobObject));
    } else {
        return string.Empty; 
    }
}
```